# Trouble understanding json formatting

Tags: pandas

I'm having trouble reading this json data set into pandas.

I see that there's a header, then each line of data starts with "dataset", but I can't seem to find a way to read it into Pandas that works. If I use the following:

df = pd.read_json(data)

I get "ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>".

I tried the following and no luck, with various errors:

```
df = pd.json_normalize([data])
df = pd.read_json(data)
df = pd.read_json(data, orient='records')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Any suggestions?

```
{'header': {'extracted': '2023-04-12T08:29:44Z',
  'id': 'NOMIS-DATA',
  'prepared': '2023-04-12T08:29:44Z',
  'sender': {'contact': {'email': 'support@nomisweb.co.uk',
    'name': 'Nomis',
    'telephone': '+441913342680',
    'uri': 'http://www.nomisweb.co.uk'},
   'id': 'NOMIS'},
  'source': 'ONS Crown Copyright Reserved',
  'test': 'false',
  'truncated': 'true',
  'uri': 'https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_1414_1/geography/TYPE276.data.json'},
 'obs': [{'dataset': {'value': 'NM_1414_1',
    'description': 'LC1117EW - Sex by age'},
   'geography': {'value': 1157631631,
    'description': 'LL68 9',
    'geogcode': 'LL68 9'},
   'c_sex': {'value': 0, 'description': 'All persons'},
   'c_age': {'value': 0, 'description': 'All categories: Age'},
   'measures': {'value': 20100, 'description': 'Value'},
   'freq': 'A',
   'time_format': {'value': 'P1Y', 'description': 'Annual'},
   'unit': {'value': 'PER', 'description': 'Persons'},
   'time': {'value': 2011, 'description': 2011},
   'obs_value': {'value': 5092,
    'description': 'Persons Value for LL68 9 (geography) for 2011 from LC1117EW - Sex by age'},
   'obs_status': {'value': 'A', 'description': 'Normal Value'},
   'obs_conf': {'value': 'F', 'description': 'Free (free for publication)'},
   'obs_round': {'value': 1, 'description': 'Rounded to 1'},
   'urn': 'Nm-1414d1d32176e0d1157631631d0d0d20100'},
  {'dataset': {'value': 'NM_1414_1', 'description': 'LC1117EW - Sex by age'},
   'geography': {'value': 1157631631,
    'description': 'LL68 9',
    'geogcode': 'LL68 9'},
   'c_sex': {'value': 0, 'description': 'All persons'},
   'c_age': {'value': 1, 'description': 'Age under 1'},
   'measures': {'value': 20100, 'description': 'Value'},
   'freq': 'A',
   'time_format': {'value': 'P1Y', 'description': 'Annual'},
   'unit': {'value': 'PER', 'description': 'Persons'},
   'time': {'value': 2011, 'description': 2011},
   'obs_value': {'value': 65,
    'description': 'Persons Value for LL68 9 (geography), Age under 1 (Age) for 2011 from LC1117EW - Sex by age'},
   'obs_status': {'value': 'A', 'description': 'Normal Value'},
   'obs_conf': {'value': 'F', 'description': 'Free (free for publication)'},
   'obs_round': {'value': 1, 'description': 'Rounded to 1'},
   'urn': 'Nm-1414d1d32176e0d1157631631d0d1d20100'},
  {'dataset': {'value': 'NM_1414_1', 'description': 'LC1117EW - Sex by age'},
...
```

Comment: What you want is not fully clear and your input is incomplete, but try `pd.json_normalize(data)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mozway - unfortunately it just gives me one line of data.

Comment: Thus the need for a minimal reproducible example (no `...`), **and the matching expected output**. Maybe `pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='obs')`/`pd.json_normalize(data['obs'])`?

Comment: The original has 24960 entries so I'm not sure how much to put on here. That said, pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='obs') has worked - thanks!

Comment: You're welcome (then the question is probably not really needed, you could delete it) ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='obs')
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.